# postgresql query json sub elements in where clause or alternative for json_exists() oracle funtion in postgresql

Tags: java, json, oracle, postgresql

I have some json similar to the json below stored in a postgres json column. I have to prepare where conditions on the json's, like **where entrySource of type mobile is equals to true or not and timeSheetEntry object existed or not.**

**Json samples:**

```
[
  {
    "calculationMethodID": "TimeEntryCommon",
    "inputs": {
      "defaultStartTime": "08:00",
      "supportedEntryTypes": {
        "timeSheetEntry": {
          "type": "TotalHours"
        }
      },
      "maxShift": {
        "breakDuration": "PT2H",
        "length": "PT14H"
      }
    }
  }
]

[
  {
    "calculationMethodID": "TimeEntryCommon",
    "inputs": {
      "defaultStartTime": "08:00",
      "supportedEntryTypes": {
        "punchEntry": {
          "entryCodes": [
            "In",
            "TakeMeal",
            "Out"
          ],
          "entrySource": {
            "mobile": true,
            "clock": true,
            "ivr": false,
            "web": true
          }
        }
      },
      "maxShift": {
        "breakDuration": "PT2H",
        "length": "PT14H"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have written this sql condition to check the json data contains particular object/value or not, here 'client_policy_js' is a column name of type json:

**Query**

```
SELECT p.pol_name,p.pol_oid FROM PYR_CLIENT_POLICY_OPTION p
WHERE p.status    =1
AND (json_exists(client_policy_js, '$?        
(@.inputs.supportedEntryTypes.punchEntry.entrySource.clock == true)')
OR json_exists(client_policy_js, 
'$.inputs.supportedEntryTypes.timeSheetEntry'))
AND ((p.eff_date BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) AND TRUNC(sysdate))
OR (p.eff_date_end BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) AND TRUNC(sysdate))
OR (p.eff_date     < TRUNC(sysdate)
AND p.eff_date_end > TRUNC(sysdate)))
```

**Please help me with alternative for following oracle query in PostgreSQL:**

```
WHERE (json_exists(client_policy_js, '$?(@.inputs.supportedEntryTypes.punchEntry.entrySource.clock == true)') 
   OR json_exists(client_policy_js, '$.inputs.supportedEntryTypes.timeSheetEntry'))
```

Comment: Please write better questions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres 12, you can simply replace `json_exists()` with `jsonb_path_exists()`

```
WHERE (jsonb_path_exists(client_policy_js, '$?(@.inputs.supportedEntryTypes.punchEntry.entrySource.clock == true)') 
       OR jsonb_path_exists(client_policy_js, '$.inputs.supportedEntryTypes.timeSheetEntry'))
```

If you are using an older version, you need to use the `#>>` operator to extract the value at the specified path. Use the `->` operator to get the first array element:

```sql
WEHERE (client_policy_js -> 0 #>> '{inputs,supportedEntryTypes,punchEntry,entrySource,clock}'::text[] = 'true'
        OR client_policy_js -> 0 #>> '{inputs,supportedEntryTypes,timeSheetEntry}'::text[] is not null)
```